# php lost $_SESSION value after click other site

Tags: php, session

I have a method, in which I (twice) access this value:

```
$_SESSION['loggedinUser'];
```

The first time it works fine, but the second time the value has been lost.

```
 public function View($view, $model) {
    if (! isset($_POST['regist'])
            && ! isset($_POST['back'])
            && ! isset($_POST['login'])
            && ! isset($_GET['logout'])
            && ! isset($_GET['note_list'])
            && ! isset($_GET['file_list'])
            && ! isset($_GET['profile'])
            && ! isset($_GET['action'])) {       // LOGIN VIEW
        $view->login();
    }

    if (isset($_POST['regist'])) {               // REGIST
        $view->regist();
    }

    if (isset($_POST['back'])){                  // BACK
        $view->login();
    }

    if (isset($_POST['login'])) {                //LOGIN AND LOGGED IN VIEW
        $username = $_POST['user_name'];
        $pw = $_POST['pw'];

        if ($model->checLoginstatus($username, $pw) == true) {
            $id = $_SESSION['loggedInUser'];    // session is working fine
            session_start();
            $fname = $model->getNameToSession("user", "id", $id, 'firstname');
            $lname = $model->getNameToSession("user", "id", $id, 'lastname');
            echo "" . var_dump($id);
            $view->LoggedIn($fname . " " . $lname, null);
        }
    }

    switch ($_GET['action']) {
        case 'note_list':
            session_start();
            $id = $_SESSION['loggedInUser'];  // session gives back NULL

            $title = $model->getNameToSession("note", "user_id", $id, 'title');
            echo "" . var_dump($_SESSION['loggedInUser']);
            echo "" . var_dump($title);
            echo "<a href='#'>" . $title . "</a>";
            break;
        case 'logout':
            session_start();
            session_unset();
            session_destroy();
            header("Location:/");
            break;
    }
}
```

What am I doing wrong that the value is lost?

Comment: does `($_GET['action'] == 'note_list')` on the second request?

Comment: `session_start()` should be at the top of your document, before any output. You are first defining your session variable and AFTER that you are using `session_start();` That won't work, my friend.

Comment: @entiendoNull Thank you so much man , it's work!

Answer (score 0):

You should include `session_start()` at the top of your document

```
<?php
session_start();

// rest of your code goes here

?>
```

Without `session_start()` your `$_SESSION` variables that you set before won't be carried over to this page.